# Find out what values occurs the most in my collection and its proportion

Tags: r

I have tried around with R a little bit and currently I am facing the following problem:

I have a table `data` with some number values stored in it's attribute `foo`. Now, if I want to get the tables of proportion out of it, I can use the following command:

```
prop.table(table(data$foo))
```

which works for me and produces the following output (this is just a part of it):

```
[1] 0.005271318 0.005271318 0.003875969 0.004031008 0.005581395 0.005736434 0.004031008 0.005891473 0.006046512
```

What I would like to do now is to find out which proportion is the highest, which I did with:

```
proportions <- prop.table(table(data$foo))
max(proportions)
```

My problem is to do the next step: Find out (programmatically) which value of my `data$foo` is the corresponding value to my output of `max(proportions)`.

So if I have the value `0.05` as my max(proportions), I would like to find all the values that occur with `0.05%` chance in my data-set (which might also be more than one value, since my `sum(proportions==mymax)` produces the output `2`).

I tried around with `prop.table(data$foo==mymax)` where `mymax <- max(proportions)`, which does (of course) not work out the way I would like it to. It just produces a list of Boolean values.

How could I possibly do that?

I created some random data for an example:

```
> dput(foo)
c(33L, 41L, 27L, 36L, 46L, 35L, 24L, 45L, 46L, 31L, 43L, 25L, 
44L, 48L, 24L, 35L, 22L, 25L, 23L, 21L, 25L, 43L, 40L, 33L, 28L, 
24L, 21L, 35L, 24L, 46L, 44L, 29L, 36L, 32L, 40L, 32L, 26L, 34L, 
37L, 49L, 46L, 36L, 46L, 38L, 41L, 36L, 32L, 50L, 29L, 23L, 37L, 
50L, 25L, 36L, 41L, 47L, 35L, 41L, 46L, 22L, 34L, 39L, 31L, 32L, 
46L, 40L, 33L, 29L, 48L, 23L, 47L, 40L, 37L, 38L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
28L, 31L, 26L, 30L, 25L, 32L, 49L, 31L, 47L, 20L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 
38L, 30L, 41L, 41L, 50L, 32L, 41L, 49L, 21L, 49L, 26L, 21L, 29L, 
20L, 47L, 24L, 26L, 42L, 50L, 25L, 36L, 42L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 28L, 
43L, 21L, 33L, 25L, 26L, 50L, 25L, 39L, 38L, 36L, 44L, 50L, 24L, 
45L, 39L, 39L, 35L, 25L, 37L, 36L, 38L, 41L, 24L, 42L, 34L, 29L, 
35L, 20L, 40L, 41L, 20L, 49L, 45L, 20L)


> prop.table(table(foo))
foo
         20          21          22          23          24          25          26          27          28          29 
0.033333333 0.053333333 0.013333333 0.020000000 0.046666667 0.060000000 0.033333333 0.006666667 0.033333333 0.033333333 
         30          31          32          33          34          35          36          37          38          39 
0.020000000 0.033333333 0.040000000 0.033333333 0.026666667 0.040000000 0.053333333 0.026666667 0.033333333 0.026666667 
         40          41          42          43          44          45          46          47          48          49 
0.033333333 0.060000000 0.020000000 0.020000000 0.020000000 0.020000000 0.046666667 0.026666667 0.013333333 0.033333333 
         50 
0.040000000 

> myprop <- prop.table(table(foo))
> max(myprop)
[1] 0.06


> sum(myprop)
[1] 1
```

Now I know, that the highest proportion occurring in my data is `0.06` and occurs only once, right? What I would like to know how is: What value is that? What I can do is:

```
> myprop==max(myprop)
foo
   20    21    22    23    24    **25**    26    27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  **TRUE** FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
   40    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So the value I look for would be 25, but there has to be another way than searching this table manually. I just can't make it out.

Comment: Please provide some sample data with `dputs()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are ignoring the table names that you are being provided with:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 3)
(proportions <- prop.table(table(x)))
# x
#    1    2    3 
# 0.50 0.25 0.25 
max(proportions)
# [1] 0.5 
names(proportions)[which.max(proportions)]
# [1] "1"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for!